# Why i get this error when trying to retrieve data from db golang gorm?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, go-gorm

This is how i am trying to retrieve data

```
func getBoard(c *gin.Context) {
  var board models.Board
  database.DB.Where("id = ?", 1).Find(&board)
  c.JSON(http.StatusOK, board)
}
```

and in postman i get all values right but todos is null

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "owner": 20,
    "name": "name",
    "generated_link": "",
    "todos": null
}
```

in logs i see this error:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 4, name "todos": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]models.TodoStructure
```

this is model:

```
type Board struct {
    Id     uint `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement;unique" json:"id"`
    Owner  uint `json:"owner"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    GeneratedLink string `gorm:"default:''" json:"generated_link"`
    Todos []TodoStructure `gorm:"type:jsonb;" json:"todos"`
}

type TodoStructure struct {
    Id string `json:"id"`
    Text string `json:"text"`
    Completed bool `json:"completed"`
    Important bool `json:"important"`
}
```

Please help how to get rid of this error and get todos rightly.
I tried to search in google but no result.
I am using gorm and postgresql as db

Comment: The driver does not know how to convert a []byte to the slice of ToDoStructure.   What is the format of the data stored in the column?  If its JSON, then get the column as a slice of bytes and write to the response.

Comment: @PenélopeStevens it's JSONB this is screenshot how it would be [screenshot](https://ibb.co/sPdf8nT)

Comment: @PenélopeStevens if you know or you have an idea how to solve this write the code please

Comment: @rejs, copy the json text in that screenshot, between theoutside-most `{` and `}`, and paste it into the question .

Comment: You can follow here https://medium.com/iostrap/manage-postgresql-json-data-with-go-golang-b0ae416972c5